# Random variables - proof of convergence in probability

Tags: probability, self-study, random-variable, convergence

I've got this exercise from lecture notes, but I couldn't find an answer.

For each positive integer $n$, let $X_{n}$ be a non-negative random variable with $\mathbb{E}[X_{n}] < \infty$.
Prove that if $\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{E}[X_{n}] = 0$, then $X_{n} \xrightarrow{\mathbb{P}} 0$, i.e., for every $\epsilon > 0$, $\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{P}[|X_{n}| \geq \epsilon] = 0$.

I tried using Chebyshev inequality, but it goes nowhere and not noticing my mistakes is driving me mad. I'd be glad if someone can give me a hint, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Markov Inequality](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Markov%27s_inequality), we have $P(X\geq a)\leq \frac{E[X]}{a}$, where $a$ is positive and $X$ is a non-negative random variable. If we apply the same here:

$$P(X_n\geq \epsilon)\leq \frac{E[X_n]}{\epsilon} \rightarrow \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}P(X_n\geq \epsilon)\leq \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{E[X_n]}{\epsilon}=0$$

So, we have $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}P(X_n\geq \epsilon)\leq 0$, which means it is equal to $0$, since a probability value is non-negative. Also, since the variable is non-negative, we have $X_n=|X_n|$, which finally yields $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}P(|X_n|\geq\epsilon)=0$, i.e. $X_n\xrightarrow{\mathbb{P}} 0$.